# Cross Cannizzarro reaction for ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-reduction, organic-oxidation

I want to ask that cross cannizzarro could be possible between any aldehyde + ketone mixture(without alpha H) and we get products as aldehyde get oxidised and ketone get reduced(along with self oxidations and reduction products of aldehyde)? Is it correct?

I think it is possible after going through the mechanism but searched in different books and doesn't get anything about it...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86573/how-can-this-ketone-show-cannizzaro-reaction/86592#86592

Comment: @user55119 I think it isn't a duplicate of that question. In that question it is asked for a special type of ketone and not following in same mechanism as of Cannizzarro. But I am asking in general they give reaction or not (any ketone)